# What is the difference between using !-command or system()?

Tags: matlab, unix

what is the difference between using the 'system' command and the `!` character in MATLAB for sending commands to OS, in UNIX environment? Any of them is faster than the other?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself with `tic` and `toc`

Answer (score 2):

[`!`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html) just executes the system command, and prints whatever its output is to the MATLAB command prompt. The exit code is lost.

[`system()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) does the same, but it allows you to capture both the output and exitcode into variables. The output of the system command is not echoed to the MATLAB command prompt.

Since `!` is just a bit of syntactic sugar, I expect little performance difference between the two commands. But, as always, [profiling](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) is the only way to really answer that question for your particular case and setup.

See also [`dos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dos.html), [`unix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unix.html).